# Creating XML file with php and saving it but file is not in folder

Tags: php, xml

I have a simple form and I want to store the contents in an xml-file using php, however, for some reason the file won't be stored in the same folder as my html- and php-file and I can't seem to figure out why as, according to other people on here, this should be the case. 
Is there an error within my code or is there any other way to do this?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="profile.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="create_xml" value="true">
            <label for="name">Name: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <label for="email">E-mail: </label><br> 
            <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <label for="textbox">Write something: </label><br>
            <textarea name="textbox" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the php-file (yes I know that it doesn't store the input yet, for now I wanted to figure out how to save the file to the folder where my other documents are stored so I didn't bother to implement the rest yet).

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php 
        $xml = new DOMDocument();

        $album = $xml->createElement("Album");
        $track = $xml->createElement("Track");
        $album ->appendChild($track);
        $xml->appendChild($album);

        echo $xml->saveXML();
        $xml->save("/test.xml");
    ?>  

</body>
</html>
```

If you  guys need any additional explanation or if anything is unclear, please let me know and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`save`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) method from `DOMDocument` expect one required parameter that is the path to save the file.
When you set the path to `/test.xml`, you're saving the file in the root of your server.
If you want to save on the same folder that the script is running, remove the slash before the filename or, if you want to save the file on a specific dir, like `documents`, for example, set it to `documents/fileName.xml`.

Comment: I tried that as well, however, it was nowhere to be found. But it is correct that, technically, a new xml file should be created in the folder where my html and php is, right?

Comment: first, does the dir have write permission? secong, try to comment the `echo $xml->saveXML();` line and run the script again. third, you can try something like this: `$strxml = $xml->saveXML(); $handle = fopen("yourxmlfile.xml", "w"); fwrite($handle, $strxml); fclose($handle);`.

Comment: I gave the file all permissions and I'll try the other stuff you mentioned really quick

Comment: Thank you very much, commenting echo $xml->saveXML(); did the trick. Could you explain why that worked?

Comment: I just tested it on my server running `PHP v7.1.11` and it works perfectly without commenting the `saveXML()` method. Maybe it can be a (mis)config on your PHP server. Try to check the `error.log` and see if there is some notice or error.

Comment: Yeah I just played around with the HTML and suddenly it didn't work again, I'll do that!